# Netbeans can't open project or anything

Tags: java, netbeans

I have this problem: Netbeans runs and I can create a new project, but if I click on an open project or open a file the programs exit and close. Also when I tried to add the `.jar` driver to create a connection it does the same thing. So I can't add or open anything.

Things to know:
I bought a new SSD for my laptop, I did a clean installation. It's a Windows 10 creator update 1703 compilation (the last build). I re-downloaded Netbeans, fully uninstalled it, and then installed it again and I can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to this bug in Java JRE 1.8.0_131-b11.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179014

It only happens when Windows 'God Mode' is active (read the comments).

Uninstall JRE 1.8.0_131-b11 and delete the 'God Mode Folder' on the desktop and the problem is gone. I was able to reinstall Netbeans and it is running fine.

Comment: Awesome! When I deleted GM it worked. However, a better solution is to install a newer JDK and change netbeans.conf to correct path. In my case `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181"`

Comment: Sorry for the delay... It worked perfectly after I unninstaled the God Mode(Actually I just moved the GM from Desktop to My Documents folder :)

Answer (score 25):

If you had Netbeans installation over **Java 9** then Please note *Netbeans does not work with Java 9*. Proof: https://forums.netbeans.org/topic68000.html

This solution is for Windows, but the same logic is applied in Linux too.

**Solution1:**
You have to edit `netbeans.conf` file to your java installation path. You can find `netbeans.conf` inside `etc` folder of Netbeans installation folder. (By default is the program files folder)

Make your `netbeans.conf` like below.
Eg, `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144"`

**Solution2:** -- If you don't want to edit your `netbeans.conf`.

Install `java 8` (32 bit or 64 bit whatever). Copy `jdk1.8.0_144` and `jre1.8.0_144` folders from `program files (x86)/java /` to `program files/java/`. Inside `program files/java` folder, rename `jdk1.8.0_144` to `jdk-9` and `jre1.8.0_144` to `jre-9`.

You are done.

Comment: This is really the right answer. Accepted answer should be changed.

Comment: Netbeans _8.2 and below_ do not run on Java 9. Netbeans _9 and above_ run fine on Java 9. This answer is outdated.

Comment: I found this comment when I was having trouble trying to install netbeans 8.2.  It pointed me in the right direction.  Only thing I did differently was to rename the originial conf file to netbeans-original.conf. Created another one to reflect the correct path to my jdk. Note: The path didn't have to be in the (x86) folder and I didn't have to change the name of my jdk for future use.  

netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211"

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the reinstallation you need to clean up from files the "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1" folder.

Comment: (This solution is worked for me)  Are you deleted the GOD MODE before?  Because I was get rid of the GOD MODE before I tried out the solution.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem on Big Sur Mac OS by editing `netbeans.conf`, note the "Contents/Home".

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: big thanks, this also worked for me on Catalina

Answer (score 2):

Right it is due to the issue https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179014 which is already investigated. This issue only observed on Windows 10 x64, build 1703. Deleting the GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C} will resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it by yourself by just adding the following line in .conf file in the netbeans installation directory folder:

netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Help -> About` and delete both the contents of the **User Directory** and **Cache Directory**

Here's a screenshot of that:

[image]

Afterwards restart/start up netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the path of `netbeans.exe` or `netbeans64.exe` doesn't have numbers or non-english characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the path of the folder. Mine is just on desktop, then I moved it inside another folder. I got the same issue, then I put it back on its original place and everything works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the below mentioned steps to fix this issue:**

1. Close Netbeans if opened
2. Download Java 8 jdk from
   *https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html*
3. Install it
4. Delete the folder /java/jdk-13/
5. Open Netbeans again
6. Select **Yes** in the prompt ( To use the newly installed jdk )
7. Viola you can create new projects and files

Answer (score -1):

I am using `netBeans8.2`. Just click on **Open Project** and select old project then all projects load automatically:

[image: Demonstration]