# Can't open new project or file with NetBeans

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, jvm

I am a newbie to Linux environment. I have followed instructions to install NetBeans on my Ubuntu (on a VirtualBox VM), but when i open the NetBeans application and try open a new project or file, it doesn't respond.
Tried to follow instruction from this fix:
[Netbeans can't open project or anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546590/netbeans-cant-open-project-or-anything)
but, i couldn't edit netbeans.conf from **netbeans_jdkhome="usr/lib/jvm/default-java"** to **netbeans_jdkhome="usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"** which i only guessed should be the correct path (see pic of jvm folder), but i had no permission to edit the file. Tried **chmod 777 netbeans.conf** to allow permission, but the output says the operation is not allowed. Tried also to copy the file to other location edit and replace, but didn't have permission to delete the original **netbeans.conf**

Entering **java -version** in the terminal show **java version "1.8.0_202"** please advise what I need to do to be able to open new project and files on NetBeans

[image: jvm folder]

Comment: updated the link

Answer (score 0):

Some times it may happen because NetBeans is trying to access Java through an invalid path. So did you try reinstalling both Java and NetBeans? Uninstall both of them first and try to reinstall them.